# JS and CSS fail to load in browser when asp.net core app hosted in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am testing docker on Ubuntu Linux 20.07 and can successfully host an asp.net Core web app in a container and route container port 80 to the host port 80 like this..

Here I mount a volume to the aspnet container. Whipover contains my asp.net code.

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/Whipover -p 80:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
```

After publishing, I can then run the app no problem inside the container with

```
dotnet Whipover/Whipover/Whipover/bin/Debug/net5.0/publish/Whipover.dll
```

However.. the assets folder in the browser shows empty files and the images are not there.. so it has no CSS or JS.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Realised that if I publish the files to an output path for example..

```
dotnet publish -o ./Run
```

and then navigate to Run inside container and call

```
dotnet Whipover.dll
```

Then it works and loads all the assets.. bizarre! it didnt work when I navigated to the bin folder. There was an issue with wwwroot.